# Struts2 addActionError, error duplicate in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I am encountering a weird error using struts2's addActionError method.

My code in Action Class is:

```
this.addActionError(e.getMessage()); 
forward = ERROR;
```

STRUTS.xml:

```xml
 <action name="test" class="test">
    <result name="success">/struts/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/struts/error.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="MyInterceptorStack" />
</action>
```

where MyInterceptorStack is:

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="MyInterceptorStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
    <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging" />
    <interceptor-ref name="profiling" />
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven" />
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" />
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
            <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
    <interceptor-ref name="DeltaInterceptor" />
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods">
                    input,back,cancel,browse
            </param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
            <param name="excludeMethods">
                    input,back,cancel,browse
            </param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>
```

My JSP:

```xml
<div><s:actionerror/></div>
```

Message should be:
[image]

But the result duplicates as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is there any good reason defining your own interceptor stack and not using default one?

Comment: @AlekdandrM Likely because of the custom interceptor.

Comment: I would look at the source code of DeltaInterceptor to see what it is doing first - an unusual error coupled with a custom interceptor ...

Comment: How did you configured your DeltaInterceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `struts.xwork.chaining.copyErrors = true` set in your *struts.properties* or *struts.xml* ?

It would override normal behaviour, giving chain interceptor the ability to preserve action error messages through chains...  who knows how it would act with no chains (it's possible that it copies them the same, assuming you use chain interceptor only with chained results, when this var is set to true)...

just a try.

EDIT: can you print out a line from java when you add the message ?

```
this.addActionError(e.getMessage()); 
System.out.println("Setting action error");
forward = ERROR;
```

just to check that the action is not called twice for some reason...

Comment: It's the chaining interceptor that uses that setting, though, IIRC, although I could be mis-remembering.

Comment: Absolutely Dave, i wrote that. My guess was: if you set this specific setting for chain interceptor, and you use a stack with chain interceptor (like the one he's using), MAYBE the copy-errors functionality is done even for the non-chained mappings... it's just a try, as i said, never say never...